# Set delegate as calling class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a helper method I use to set up video inputs and outputs.  Within the helper method I need to set the delegate, but would prefer to have the delegate method in the calling class.  My current line of code is:

```
[captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
```

How would I specify the calling class MyAVViewController as the delegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an instance of your MyAVViewController, which you can pass in as the delegate:

```
 [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:avViewController queue:queue];
```

You'll have to pass your avViewController as a parameter to your helper method to achieve this:

```
- (void)helperMethodWithDelegate:(id<AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>)delegate
{
    // do stuff
    [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:delegate queue:queue];
}
```

Make sure that your avViewController (or whatever you choose to pass in) conforms to the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate protocol.

Comment: Thanks!  So in MyAVViewController.h, I add:                 id <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate> delegate;